# Automatically Update a Variable from Tkinter Entry Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a real-time searching algorithm in GUI with tkinter in Python 3.
So I have this window and entry box for typing keywords in for searching:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.title('Window')

var = StringVar()

root.SearchBox = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=var, font='Fixedsys 28')
root.SearchBox.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, height=50, width=400, anchor="center")
search_input = var.get()
```

What should I put here, without an enter button for the search box

```
...Some codes here...
```

To get the following results?

When the tkinter window is already open
and some keywords typed into the search entry box

```
>>>print(search_input)
Search Terms
```

and as soon as the search entry box `search_input =! ''` 
how could I get a global variable to change, say
`is_entry_box_empty = False` to `is_entry_box_empty = True`

I found this to be impossible without threading, since the GUI window will block any codes after it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trace changes in the textvariable:

```
var.trace('w',var_change_callback_function)
```

and write a function to deal with the changes.